# regexp to split a string using '%' character but ignore '\%'

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to split a string using a `%` delimiter. However, if there is a `\` right before `%` then `\%` should be ignored.
So `%` - delimiter
`\%` - not delimiter.
From string `"Hi %username%, how are you? \%"` I want to get `["Hi ", "username", ", how are you? \%"]` array.
Now I ended up with `[^(\\%)]?%` but when I use it in split method of String class I lose first letters of each string in array

Comment: [You can use `(?<!\\)%`](https://regex101.com/r/8dQAj2/1)

Comment: If you honor escape a delimiter, then you must honor an escaped escape. That's the way language is, no getting around it. There is no `if there is a \ right before %` scenario, don't work that way. A big -1 for not knowing this, therefore choosing a junk answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind regex for splitting:

```
(?<!\\)%
```

`(?<!\\)` is a negative lookbehind that asserts we don't have a backslash `\` before `%`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dQAj2/1/)

For Java use:

```
String[] arr = string.split("(?<!\\\\)%");
```